# store result in for loop in python

Tags: python

Though it might be a very simple problem but I am not able to store output. He is my code. I did tf-idf for text similarity measure:

```
data=pd.read_csv('name.csv')
import nltk, string
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

    nltk.download('punkt') # if necessary...


    stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
    remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

    def stem_tokens(tokens):
        return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

    '''remove punctuation, lowercase, stem'''
    def normalize(text):
        return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

    def cosine_sim(text1, text2):
        tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
        return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]

    cnt=np.array(np.arange(0,13091))
    indx=[]

    for i in cnt:
        indx.append(cosine_sim(data['names'][i], data['names'][i+1]))
```

After executing the code I am geting following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-14badf13ad3b> in <module>()
     25 
     26 for i in cnt:
---> 27     indx.append(cosine_sim(data['names'][i], data['names'][i+1]))

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    621         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    622         try:
--> 623             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    624 
    625             if not is_scalar(result):

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   2558         try:
   2559             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2560                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2561         except KeyError as e1:
   2562             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
```

Though, if I write print statement, I am getting the output:

```
for i in cnt:
    print cosine_sim(data['names'][i], data['names'][i+1])
```

I am not getting where am I making mistakes. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That stack trace doesn't make sense. You're getting a KeyError, inside a `try` that explicitly catches `KeyError`? Also, you seem to have cut off part of the end of the message.

Comment: `data` value not set anywhere in code. It is probably None type.

Comment: Are you actually waiting for the prints to finish or do you break ? Your example unfortunately does not run as-is, numpy is not imported and data is not existing. Why are you using a static number to iterate, you probably want to iterate knowing the len(data) and then you may want to iterate using enumerate, no need to create the array with indexes first. Please fix the code so it runs that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry, I have modified the code. I have imported the data in the code. This is the original code